# YAJSW tray icon not connecting

Tags: java, service, playframework, wrapper

I'm finalising the release of a play application, wrapped into a windows service using Yet Another Java Service Wrapper. I have the wrapper working but would prefer the tray functionality.

When using the runConsole.bat file I have the following log message.
The YAJSW properties wrapper.tray = true and multicast is set (same error if I manually specify port).

This is the log file for YAJSW. The issue seems to be due to YAJSW itself as clearly the Play application is running correctly. Thanks

```
INFO|2924/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:37|Play server process ID is 2924
INFO|2924/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:38|[info] play - Application started (Prod)
INFO|2924/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:39|[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:39|[id: 0x4de7d7d8, /10.1.0.27:57385 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:39|[id: 0x3727fe37, /10.1.0.27:57405 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:42|[id: 0x3727fe37, /10.1.0.27:57405 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:42|[id: 0xc0f24c88, /10.1.0.27:57406 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:45|[id: 0xc0f24c88, /10.1.0.27:57406 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:45|[id: 0xc2a4c22b, /10.1.0.27:57407 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:48|[id: 0xc2a4c22b, /10.1.0.27:57407 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:48|[id: 0x2ebec4b7, /10.1.0.27:57408 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:51|[id: 0x2ebec4b7, /10.1.0.27:57408 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:52|[id: 0xfaa17906, /10.1.0.27:57409 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:54|[id: 0xfaa17906, /10.1.0.27:57409 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:54|[id: 0xa8a19b37, /10.1.0.27:57410 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:57|[id: 0xa8a19b37, /10.1.0.27:57410 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:51:57|[id: 0x33287ab1, /10.1.0.27:57411 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:00|[id: 0x33287ab1, /10.1.0.27:57411 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:01|[id: 0xa6285588, /10.1.0.27:57412 => /10.1.0.27:57366] connected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:04|[id: 0xa6285588, /10.1.0.27:57412 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:04|[id: 0x8249b3c5, /10.1.0.27:57413 => /10.1.0.27:57366] exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:07|[id: 0x8249b3c5, /10.1.0.27:57413 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:07|[id: 0xc9bab6d6, /10.1.0.27:57414 => /10.1.0.27:57366] exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:10|[id: 0xc9bab6d6, /10.1.0.27:57414 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:10|[id: 0xbd254ea0, /10.1.0.27:57415 => /10.1.0.27:57366] exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:13|[id: 0xbd254ea0, /10.1.0.27:57415 :> /10.1.0.27:57366] disconnected
WARNING|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-08-13 10:52:13|[id: 0xa00debfb, /10.1.0.27:57416 => /10.1.0.27:57366] exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: This *question* was so useful for me! I couldn't for the life of me figure out why my service was constantly disconnecting and reconnecting, then running out of heap space. Disabling the tray fixed it!